# sql server decimal formatting in query string

Tags: sql-server-2005, number-formatting

I've found several solutions online, but none that *really* do what I'm looking for. So, here goes..
I have several columns in my table of type numeric(8, 4), numeric(8, 5), etc, and when I retrieve the data it comes with all the trailing 0's. Is there a way I can format it so it leaves off all the trailing and leading 0's? I don't want to specify a length of precision. Here's some examples of what I'm looking for:

```
145.5000 -> 145.5
145.6540 -> 145.654
73.4561 -> 73.4561
37.0000 -> 37
```

Thank you much!

Comment: do it need to be converted in the SQL statment? can't you manage it with your programing language

Comment: I could.. but it seems like that would be much more tedious

Comment: just wait for anwsers but SQL has no specific functions as programming languages have.

Comment: @Luis word. and there you have it! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float and real are both approximate data types so this may not work with every value you come across.  Given that you only have 4 or 5 digits of precision, I think this method will always work, but you'll want to test it pretty well before implementing this in to production.

```
DECLARE @d DECIMAL(8,5)

select @d = 5.12030

Select Convert(Float, @d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to do this in front-end code

so how will you distinguish between `0.37`  and `37.0` if all you want is `37`?

Here is one way in SQL

Replace 0 with space and do trim and then replace space back to 0

example

edit: missed the trailing dot before..added that as a case statement

```
DECLARE @d DECIMAL(8,5)
select @d = 5.12030

SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@d),'0',' '))),' ','0'),1) = '.'
THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@d),'0',' '))),' ','0'),'.','')
ELSE
REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@d),'0',' '))),' ','0') END
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Very complex, I didn't think it would take that much data manip. Perhaps it would be better to do this in code

Comment: I wish the ROUND() func would just take a number, and give the option to leave out length :x

Comment: What a monster! :) Why not use a subselect? You could then avoid repeating all those nested functions.